# Automatically add \vfill for breakable tcolorbox

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox

I'm using `tcolorbox` with nested `tcolorbox`es, the upper level ones being breakable. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,title=My breakable box]
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title = box1]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title = box2]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title = box3]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the huge blank space at the bottom of the first page.

Now, I'd like something like that (I got it adding an ugly `\vspace*{3cm}` between first and second box):

[image]

A bit better, in my opinion.

So my question is: would it be possible to make `tcolorbox` add automatically some kind of `\vfill` between inner boxes, once the breaking algorithm has decided where to break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an aesthetical point of view, all solutions are somewhat ugly ... the choice of what is least ugly should be finally up to you ;-)

Let's call your problem description a first 'solution', i.e. the available space is put after the first box part.

The second solution would be to put the available space inside but at the end of the first box part. `tcolorbox` supports this using the `height fixed for` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,title=My breakable box,
  height fixed for=first and middle]
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title = box1]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \vfill
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title = box2]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title = box3]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\vfill` was added for fun to show that it has no effect here.

The third solution tries to stretch the content of the first box part to cope the available space. For this, I use a patch for the `height fixed for` option. Note that this will not work properly, if the outer box has a lower part. Now, the `\vfill` comes to action:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw}

\makeatletter

\def\tcb@break@ch@fixed{%
  \ifdim\tcb@natheight<\tcb@h@page\relax%
    \tcbdimto\tcb@h@upper{\tcb@h@upper+\tcb@h@page-\tcb@natheight}%
    \setbox\tcb@upperbox=\vbox to\tcb@h@upper\relax{\unvbox\tcb@upperbox}%
    \tcbdimto\kvtcb@height@fixed{\tcb@h@page}%
    \tcb@ch@fixed%
  \else%
    \tcb@ch@natural%
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,title=My breakable box,
  height fixed for=first and middle]
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title = box1]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \vfill
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title = box2]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title = box3]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could use `after={\par\vfill}` as an option for your inner boxes to get rid of manually adding the `\vfill` commands.

Answer (score 4):

well, you can use

```
\par\vskip .5\textheight minus .5\textheight
```

which makes

[image]

but that's not fully automatic, if you make the natural size too big (eg `.75\textheight` in this case) it will fill the page and push the next box over to the next page, and if you make it too small it won't push the box to the bottom.

Doing more would probably require Thomas to pass by and poke some stretch into tcolorbox internals somewhere:-)

Comment: Thanks David (+1). I'll wait for Thomas to pass by. Maybe he could make it a bit more automatic.